# Multipart to Singlepart and Explode not working in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, multipart

I am trying to separate multipart polygons, however in case of Multipart to Singlepart program seems to be working for around 15 minutes and then it crashes and when I try to Explode I get the error:"The Explode command could not be completed."

Is there any other way to separate such polygons? 
[image]

Comment: Try dissolve with multipart set to false

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the same situation as with Multipart to Singlepart...

Comment: Have you tried repair geometry?

Comment: You, Sir, are genius. Multipoint to Singlepoint is still not working (after 3 hours I cancelled the process), but Explode did the thing. Thank you!